# Why Google+ and TTS in showing along with my activity in running app?

Tags: android, performance, admob, google-plus, ads

[image]asd

[image]

I have different activities, **I am using AdMob Advertisement and Have Added the SDK for ADMOB** and I haven't used anything related to GOOGLE+ **so why this GOOGLE+ is using 9MB and Increasing the RAM usage of my application?**

Is it because of ADS?? 
Why Google+ plus is there?
I havent Used anythings releated to the Google TTS, then WHY ?

Comment: I guess the "Provider AdsProvider is in use" part should make it clear... And, yes, injecting ads will cost you some MB of RAM.

Comment: So is it because of ADMOB ?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo why the hell is now this GOOGLE TEXT TO SPEECH ??